# OpenVAS 7 not working after apt-get update - Failed to receive data: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received

Tags: debian, security, apt, kali-linux

The problem started when my Kali installation updated OpenVAS to v7: My `admin` username for the web service stopped working so I could no longer log in.

I have tried everything I can think of to fix this (deleting all OpenVAS users, adding `admin` again, manually deleting the `.db`, and finally a purge and a reinstall via apt-get), but to no avail. I now get this when running `openvas-check-setup`:

```
Step 2: Checking OpenVAS Manager ... 
        OK: OpenVAS Manager is present in version 5.0.2.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager client certificate is present as /var/lib/openvas/CA/clientcert.pem.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database found in /var/lib/openvas/mgr/tasks.db.
        OK: Access rights for the OpenVAS Manager database are correct.
        OK: sqlite3 found, extended checks of the OpenVAS Manager installation enabled.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database is at revision 123.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager expects database at revision 123.
        OK: Database schema is up to date.
        ERROR: The number of NVTs in the OpenVAS Manager database is too low.
        FIX: Make sure OpenVAS Scanner is running with an up-to-date NVT collection and run 'openvasmd --rebuild'.
        WARNING: OpenVAS Scanner is NOT running!
        SUGGEST: Start OpenVAS Scanner (openvassd).
```

This suggests to run the OpenVAS Scanner, however it will not start:

```
root@kali:/var/log/openvas# openvas-start
Starting OpenVas Services
Starting Greenbone Security Assistant: ERROR.
Starting OpenVAS Scanner: ERROR.
Starting OpenVAS Manager: ERROR.
```

normally it takes a while for the scanner to start but on this occasion it isn't starting at all.

Checking the Scanner log shows an error that I need to rebuild/update and if I try starting the manager with `--update` or `--rebuild` gives

```
# openvasmd --progress --rebuild -v
Rebuilding NVT cache... failed.
```

and the manager log gives this message:

`Failed to receive data: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.`

**Update:** Checking the scanner log (`openvassd.messages`) shows that the scanner server is refusing the connection:

```
# tail /var/log/openvas/openvassd.messages
[Fri Dec  5 11:15:34 2014][4778] bad login attempt from 127.0.0.1
```

How do I fix OpenVAS? I'm happy to remove OpenVAS and completely reinstall it if that is the suggested fix? If so, how would I go about this?

Please let me know if I should edit my question to add specific log or other information, I'm aware that this may be the case to solve this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had to run

```
openvas-mkcert-client -n om -i
```

which I found from [this post](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?19998-OpenVAS-stoped-at-1) - this was a different issue but the same error message.

Then I could rebuild the NVT cache:

```
# openvasmd --progress --rebuild -v
Rebuilding NVT cache... done.
```

Checking the log now shows it is successful:

```
# tail /var/log/openvas/openvasmd.log 
md   main:   INFO:2014-12-05 11h29.21 utc:5383:    OpenVAS Manager
md   main:   INFO:2014-12-05 11h29.22 utc:5384:    Set to connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 9391
md   main:   INFO:2014-12-05 11h29.22 utc:5384:    Updating NVT cache.

# tail /var/log/openvas/openvassd.messages
[Fri Dec  5 11:30:45 2014][5386] Communication closed by client 
[Fri Dec  5 11:30:45 2014][5386] Client not present
```

Now I can successfully log into the web interface and use OpenVAS:

[image]
[image]